# cumulative product with pyarrow

Tags: python, math, user-defined-functions, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Is it possible to calculate the cumulative product with pyarrow lib?

I only see a cumulative sum function in the docs:
[pyarrow comulative compute functions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/compute.html#cumulative-functions)

Could someone tell me how to apply the cumulative product on a pyarrow array, maybe with UDFs?

Is there an arrow native function for cumulative product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User defined functions don't yet support [vector functions](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/31103), which cumulative product would be.

A workaround would be to call `numpy.cumprod` directly.

Comment: And having cumulative product as an arrow native function like the cumulative sum?

Comment: Open feature request about adding more cumulative functions: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/32190